# bash: .: ./import.io: cannot execute binary file

Tags: linux

I am using import.io application and while running the same it shows same error as bash: .: ./import.io: cannot execute binary file
I have download tar file from web site and after doing untar i try simple command . ./import.io to run it. but it is not working

Comment: Is the file executable? Try `chmod +x import.io` and then execute it again.

Answer (score 1):

Try making the file executable

```
chmod +x import.io
```

Then try running it

```
./import.io
```